# Is Twitter's Bootstrap mobile friendly like Skeleton?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Skeleton is made to scale to also fit mobile browsers, following the principles of [responsive web design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). Does Bootstrap offer the same?

Comment: No. Go to the project page, look at the grid (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#grid-system) and resize your browser. The grid doesn't change.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not yet - http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-bootstrap/browse_thread/thread/6db57d09f654a326?pli=1

But it will be, at some point. [The Roadmap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Roadmap) has this in for version 2.0. It's lightweight enough that in my experience you can add in your own `media queries` without much trouble.

**EDIT** - As of 1 Feb 2012, [version 2.0](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) is out, which is responsive down to mobile out of the box.

**EDIT** - As of 19 Aug 2013, [version 3.0](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/19/bootstrap-3-released/) is out, which is not only responsive but takes a mobile-first approach:

> > With Bootstrap 2, we added optional mobile friendly styles for key aspects of the framework. With Bootstrap 3, we've rewritten the project to be mobile friendly from the start. Instead of adding on optional mobile styles, they're baked right into the core. In fact, Bootstrap is mobile first. Mobile first styles can be found throughout the entire library instead of in separate files.

Comment: does this mean basic use of framework gets you mobile support for free, or do you have to accommodate it some how?  (ps thank you for revising your answer)

Comment: In Twitter's own words: _Bootstrap doesn't automatically include these media queries, but understanding and adding them is very easy and requires minimal setup._ If you download the latest version (CSS rather than LESS), you'll see the stylesheet. Stick with the structure and classes from Bootstrap and there's nothing special you need to do.

Comment: Add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> to your header.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently it should support it now.

> Originally built with only modern browsers in mind, Bootstrap has
>   evolved to include support for all major browsers (even IE7!) and,
>   with Bootstrap 2, tablets and smartphones, too.

Source: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#grid-system

If you go to the site and resize your browser, you will se it's fitting nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Yes Twitter Bootstrap's 2.0 version is based on responsive web design. look at their website: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. You will have to play around with it when you download, cause the download version does not have it. You will have to rename the responsive css, best option is to look at their website and try to reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile-friendly has many meanings. Bootstrap is responsive, which is a mobile-friendly attribute. It's also extremely heavy (it's designed for applications) - which is not mobile-friendly, especially for websites.

The Yahoo [Pure framework is about 1/10th the weight, and provides the same feature set](http://purecss.io) for websites. I'd suggest something similar over Bootstrap for a mobile website.