# Twitter Bootstrap for mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

If I want to develop an web application on mobile, so should I use Twitter Bootstrap or Jquery Mobile? Twitter Bootstrap good for mobile or not?

Answer (score 3):

As of version 2.0, Bootstrap is fully mobile compatible. There actually has been [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213657/is-twitters-bootstrap-mobile-friendly-like-skeleton) about it.

One thing you may want to keep in mind, is the purpose they're build for. jQuery mobile was created and is maintained with mobile compatibility in mind whereas Bootstrap offers it as an addition (meaning that it won't be it's main priority). If there is nothing in bootstrap that you are particularly interested in, I would go for jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you want to do..
Twitter bootstrap is a CSS framework with some javascripts on it. While jquery Mobile is javascript to create native mobile feel..
So basically they are quite different..

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap 3 is built group up for mobile first, you may want to take a look at the 3.0 branch on GitHub.  I didn't use jquery mobile in my app Django Market b/c I would have to change the backend and didn't want to invest. Bootstrap 3.0 IMHO will provide a lot of "competition" for other frameworks due to its power and simplicity

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, i've using jQuery Mobile for a simple informative application. I spent some days on the base code, then i tested it on tablets, handsets using PhoneGap and the results wasn't good. There are still some troubles on transitions for Android and iOS devices.